# download and display xml file php

Tags: php, xml, .htaccess, force-download

I need to make queries to my partners website, which, after htaccess authentication, force downloads XML file. I then need to save that data into a database.

I tried doing it like this

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
    )
));

$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

but it returns a boolean with the value FALSE. 
I havent found any information regarding te getting XML content after forced download

Comment: `file_get_contents` does not do an actual download. It captures the text content of a given file and assigns it as the value of a string-based variable.  Have you tried only using the mandatory (first) argument of the url?  Also, you don't seem to indicate "where" the XML file exists.  Is it remote or is it on same filesystem as the script?

Comment: If `file_get_contents` is indeed returning Boolean false I think it would help if you wrapped some code in a try / catch block and echo out the error message. Typically if you have `} catch (Exception $e) {` then you would echo out `$e->getMessage()` to see if an error is contributing to the return of false.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There was no error. Got it working:
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://external.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;